# trying to overwrite externaldepsdlg.h which is also in package codeblocks-headers

Tags: dpkg

OK I'm kind of confused here. After I installed Code::Blocks from the website, a little error popped up the top bar. It said that "Error: BrokenCount > 0", and that one of my packages had unmet dependencies. I instantly knew this was Code::Blocks, because I recalled seeing an error when installing it, that it couldn't install the codeblocks-contrib package and some others. I have tried apt-get install -f, and all of the suggestions, and even going into the Software Center and clicking repair, but this launches similar errors that I found in the terminal. Here's my output of sudo apt-get install -f:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  codeblocks-contrib codeblocks-dev gamin libcodeblocks0 libgamin0
  libwxsmithlib-dev
Recommended packages:
  valgrind
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  codeblocks-headers
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gamin libgamin0 libwxsmithlib-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  codeblocks-contrib codeblocks-dev libcodeblocks0
3 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/5,309 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,163 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 249992 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../codeblocks-dev_13.12-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking codeblocks-dev (13.12-3) over (13.12-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-dev_13.12-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/codeblocks/externaldepsdlg.h', which is also in package codeblocks-headers 13.12-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-dev_13.12-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The dpkg error message is explicit, both codeblocks-dev and codeblocks-headers are trying to provide the same file `/usr/include/codeblocks/externaldepsdlg.h`. Contact the maintainer of each, so they can make sure to add Conflicts to their packages.